# program doesn't work after FTP

Tags: c++, ftp

I was working on a c++ project on a remote linux server via ssh. I decided I wanted to test the files on my own machine using valgrind. I FTP-ed the project directory from the remote server to my own machine, compiled, and attempted to run.

I got the message:

> Error opening /proc/96855/stat

And based on the different arguments I ran my program with, that number between proc and stat would change.
Does anyone know what happened here? Shouldn't everything work just fine on my machine as long as I have all the .cpp and .h files necessary? It compiled just fine, so I am lost.

Comment: Did the project directory contain object files or executables? If so, did you `make clean`?

Answer (score 2):

What operating system is your local machine running?

My guess is that it doesn't support operations that the software requires (for example, trying to access processes through the `/proc` directory).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to tell FTP that this was an "image".  Try again with "image" turned on.

Another practice that I use when I FTP is to turn on hashing with  "#".  I want to be able to see that the number of bytes transferred is exactly the same as the size on my machine.

Maybe a client program like FileZilla would help as well.